# Flutter integration with springboot webservices

Tags: spring, flutter, firebase, spring-security, firebase-authentication

I am using Flutter for creating an application which will login user using firebase Auth. Token recieved from the firebase is sent with every api requests, and in server side (i.e Spring) that token's authenticity is checked and, on basis of that, respose is sent.

Is this a correct way to do user login/register and fetch data from the end points?

I tried to fetch the token from the firebase after successful login, I can also sent the token with every request, but i doubt is this the way it should work. Or i am missing something?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.